# How to bind a button in turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Note: I've already tried to find solutions from https://docs.python.org/3/ and other stack overflow questions, but I haven't been able to find it.

What I'm looking for is quite simple. While using a code like this:

```
import turtle
s = turtle.Screen()
def u():
t.forward(50)
s.onkey(u(), "Up")
s.listen()
```

It simply runs the code `u` So first of all: Why does it not wait until I press "Up"? And second, how can I make it so that it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the `onkey` and `listen` calls *outside* the `u` callback function.

Like this:

```
import turtle

def u():
    t.forward(50)

s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

s.onkey(u, "Up")
s.listen()

turtle.done()
```

Note that in `s.onkey(u, "Up")` I just have `u` **not** `u()`. The former passes the function itself to `.onkey` so it knows what function to call when the `"Up"` key event occurs. The latter just passes the result of calling `u` (which is `None`, since `u` doesn't have a `return` statement) to `.onkey`.

Also, your code omits the [`turtle.done()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.done) call. That tells turtle to go into the event loop so it will listen for events and respond to them. Without it, the script opens a turtle window and then closes it immediately.

---

BTW, the code you posted has an `IndentationError`; correct indentation is *vital* in Python.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Also about the error, I don't have that in my actual code, for some reason it wouldn't let me indent here. I assumed people would just find the main problem.

Comment: @PigglesThePig: 1). Without correct indentation we can't tell what your problem is, since we don't know if there's only the `t.forward(50)` line inside the `u` function or if all 3 lines are inside `u`. 2). The SO code editor is rather rudimentary. The easiest way to use it (IMHO) is to just paste your code into your post, select it, then press the `{}` button (or click `Ctrl-k` on your keyboard) to place it in a code block.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling the function when you put parentheses after it.  Just take those out to pass the function itself rather than what it returns:

```
import turtle
s = turtle.Screen()

def u():
    t.forward(50)

s.onkey(u, "Up")
s.listen()
```

In Python, functions are objects just like everything else.  You don't need parentheses in order to use them.  You could do `v = u` and you would be able to use `v()`.  If you were to say `u = 4`, you wouldn't be able to use `u()` any more because now `u` refers to something else.