# Console unresponsive while Turtle window is open

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

The exit command I have written is:

```
user_input = input("press Q to exit:")
if user_input == 'q':
    exit()
```

In this case after launching the program I have to minimize Turtle Window and go back to terminal and press <kbd>Q</kbd> there and press enter to terminate it.
How can I implement it so that I can simply press <kbd>Q</kbd> to close window. Is there a way to maybe mode around the command  `turtle.exitonclick`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkey I don't know turtle so I can not give a complete answer but this seems like  what you are looking for. Also, this seems like a common question so I'm pretty sure there is duplicate somewhere.

Comment: Like this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978153/how-to-bind-a-button-in-turtle or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619994/how-do-you-make-python-turtle-stop-moving

Comment: What may not be obvious is that with `exitonclick()` we just need to click on the window to close it but with `onkey(exit, "Q")` we need to both click on the window to make it the active listener and type "Q" to close it.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Set Turtle Screen :**

```
screen = turtle.Screen()
```

**2) Make Function :**

```
def close():
    exit()
```

**3) Bind Key:**

```
screen.onkey(close, "Q")
screen.listen()
```

### **so final look will be like this:**

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
def close():
    exit()

turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)

screen.onkey(close, "q")
screen.listen()

turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i dont really get your question, but i think you are looking for a bind in turtle.

Comment: Pressing simple q will close your entire turtle window, no inputs needed

Comment: Why `turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()` rather than simply `screen.mainloop()`?  Why `screen.onkey(close, "q")` instead of simply `screen.onkey(exit, "q")` and toss the `close()` function?